# Precautions for moving a SQL cluster from an old to a new datastore

Tags: sql-server, migration, clustering, storage, vmware

My storage team  wants to move a SQL cluster (2 node VM) from an old data store to Storage vMotion . What are the precautions I can take before this exercise is performed? I am planning to take database snapshots before the exercise and then shutdown the cluster and databases. The RDM's will be reconnected once the VM's have been moved to the new datastore. Are there any other best practices which I can follow before this process? Please advice.

Comment: Snapshots are not backups. Take full backups of the databases using the native `BACKUP` method, just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would:

- Run [DBCC CHECKDB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176064.aspx) on all databases prior to the move to ensure no consistency errors.
- Take full [SQL Server Backups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187510.aspx) of all user and system databases. Use native backup or your preferred third party tool.
- When taking the backup, ensure it is [verified](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/113/checking-to-make-sure-a-sql-server-backup-is-useable/).
- Run [DBCC CHECKDB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176064.aspx) on all databases post the move to ensure no consistency errors.